# How to get crash logs for React Native app?

Tags: react-native

My React Native App crashed on a tester's phone.

What is the best way to get logs of that crash? I'm using React Native 0.14.2

Comment: Use some Crashlytics library. [here](https://github.com/corymsmith/react-native-fabric) is one you can try

Comment: Hey Mark, have you tried Bugsnag?  It's much better than Crashalytics.  You should mark the other answer as the correct answer for other users that stumble upon this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Abhishek has commented, you'll have to use some monitoring tools with `crashlytics` to get such infomation.

[Fabric](https://get.fabric.io/) is a good option in this case. It comes with a [crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics) solution.

[Here is a blogpost](https://medium.com/delivery-com-engineering/add-crashlytics-to-your-react-native-ios-app-69a983a9062a#.1kajet28s) that explains in-depth on how to set it up for your app.

Here's an excerpt of features of crashlytics tool of Fabric from the blogpost

> **Crash Reporting** —It will record every single crash and its stack trace. This is way better than the iTunes Connect crash reports, which only include the info of users that opted in to share information with developers while setting up a new iPhone. It’s also not updated in real-time (you can read more about this here).
>
> **Crash Logs** — (A.K.A. CLS_LOG) If you’re familiar with Objective-C, you have probably been using “NSLog” while you’re developing your app. You should use CLS_LOG instead. There’s no difference at all when you’re debugging (whatever you’re logging will still show up in the console) but the cool part is that when a user crashes your app, all the information will be sent to Crashlytics’s servers the next time the user launches your app, including all the content that you’ve logged through CLS_LOG. So if you log information for most of the actions/events in your app, you can read the logs later and reproducing the crash should be simple.

Answer (score 10):

We just rolled out official support for [react native error reporting](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/react-native/) with Bugsnag this week which reports both JavaScript and native (Java/Cocoa) layer errors to a single dashboard.

Compared to Fabric - Bugsnag adds support for js source maps, ios symbolication, and android proguard mapping - which make a big difference.

Let me know if you have any questions or I can help in any way - I'm a founder.

Comment: I've used both crashlytics and bugsnag and bugsnag is better for sure.  Crashlytics doesn't report where in the JS the error happened so the error reports aren't very helpful.  Bugsnag does.

Answer (score 1):

A good crash log framework that reports from the javascript level I've tried recently is [Sentry](https://docs.sentry.io). More descriptive with the actual error, if it comes from he JS side.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like [Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics) does the error reporting job perfect for a native app made in android/ios.

For a react-native app, however, [Bugsnag](https://www.bugsnag.com/) looks more promising. You can explore both and see which one fits your requirements.

Comment: Crashlytics is so bad for finding crash bug with RN, it's only work for native